# Graph of questions increasing after New Years?

Tags: discussion

Recently I came across a question starting with "I want to cycle to work as a New Years resolution", which got me thinking - how much does question activity rise in January because of New Years resolutions to ride bicycles? Is there any way of seeing a graph of questions asked by month?

Comment: Aside "I want to ride to work" is fundamentally different to "I will ride to work"   and is beaten by "I will ride to work today".
The first is a vague woolly desire, the second is a plan with no definite date, and the last is ideal.  The only thing that can beat out that is "I rode to work today!"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mods have access to some of our site's analytics. We're specifically instructed not to share "the specifics" in public. So, here are some generalizations:

The number of questions and answers that have been posted over the last four months has been relatively static. There's actually been a slight drop since the New Year, but nothing that I would call statistically significant.

Our total page views are a different story. There was a slow steady decline in page views through all of Q4 2017. And, you guessed it, a spike at the beginning of January that has been more or less holding steady since then (as of Jan 18). If we go back further, we see the same thing happened at the beginning of 2017.

One interesting thing that I noted when looking further back in the past is that, as you might expect, our traffic follows a pretty predictable pattern throughout the year. There's small jump in traffic every January. Unlike the New Year's gym participation, that level of traffic holds and even begins to climb until it peaks about mid-summer, at which time it slowly declines to a low at the end of December. That pattern can be seen all the way back to the launch of our public beta in 2010 (2011 really, since we launched near the end of summer in 2010).

Answer (score 2):

Too long for a comment, but not really an answer.

Here's info available to anyone.

### https://www.quantcast.com/bicycles.stackexchange.com

- The month of July 2016 appears to have the most visits in recent history.
- This is a US centric site, so seems to be skewed a bit.

### https://www.similarweb.com/website/bicycles.stackexchange.com/

- More estimates than actual counting, take with salt.
- Claims 82% of traffic comes from searches, over direct/referrals/social media.
- Claims 45% of those referrals are from other SE sites.

### https://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/stackexchange.com

- Claims India, Japan, and China give more traffic than the UK, which is at variance with the first two sites.
- Claims 73.2% of traffic is from a search engine

---

### http://bicycles.stackexchange.com.hypestat.com/

- Doesn't measure this stack as of 2018-01-19

### http://netcraft.com

- The internet's grandaddy for measuring Numbers.  Seems to have gone away from generic monitoring.